# Does Yosemite Upgrade Destroy Bootcamp?

Tags: macos, bootcamp

I use Mavericks with Bootcamp on my iMac. 
If I upgrade Yosemite via AppStore, what happens to Bootcamp?
Can I start it as usual or will the Bootcamp partition become unusable?

Comment: Just out of sheer curiosity...what would cause you to think Apple would render the (probably) millions of Bootcamp installations out there useless with an upgrade they are heavily pushing? There would be pitchfork-wielding villagers at their gates before release night had finished if that were the case.

Comment: I saw couple of bootcamp boot problems after yosemite upgrade on Apple Discussion Forums.

Comment: @orko There are always a "couple" of problems. It's human nature

Comment: @tubedogg - Once upon a time Apple was like that. Nowadays they don't give a 5hit. The official line now seems to be is 'if something no longer works you need to buy newer hardware'

Comment: there are for sure some problems, I had to install several times , still not good as with Mavericks.

Answer (score 1):

Bootcamp is not affected by an upgrade from Mavericks to Yosemite.

Comment: We know you know, but they do not know you know, so how about a reference :)

Comment: I saw couple of bootcamp boot problems after yosemite upgrade on Apple Discussion Forums.